# Need quick way to validate proper nesting of HTML tags

Tags: html

Is there a firefox plugin or something similar I can use to validate that my html output has properly closed tags?

Answer (score 3):

You can use either the [W3 HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) or [HTML Tidy online](http://infohound.net/tidy/).

Answer (score 2):

I use this little guy [Html Validator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/249).  I like him.  The errors it makes help you find your nesting problems (along with others).  I don't know of a validator that only checks for nesting issues.

Comment: Thanks just what I needed. But please fix your link so it won't confuse others.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to check is whether or not your tags are nested and closed properly (and not other things like that all images have an `alt`, etc), then you just want to check the XML well-formedness of it.

Run it through this validator http://www.validome.org/xml/ and tick the "Well-Formedness Only" checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

The best is to install web developer tabs:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60

There you can find the link for validator and many other things.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the web developer addon for a long time.

```
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60
```

It's got an HTML validator link in the tools menu.